# How to remove a session variable after leaving the page?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

[image: search box]

After clicking on the search button I am saving the search string in a session variable and then loading the index again.

```js
$(document).on('click', '#search', function(e) {
  var search_key = $("#key").val().toLowerCase();
  var pathname = window.location.pathname;
  var arr = pathname.split("/");
  var urlStr = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/" + arr[1] + "/" + arr[2] + "/SearchData?key=" + search_key;

  $.get(urlStr, function(data) {         //calling SearchData action
    console.log(window.location);
    urlStr = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + pathname;
    window.location.href = urlStr;       //calling index action for loading the data 
  });
});
```

```js
[HttpPost]
public void SearchData(string key) {
  Session.Add("search_key", key);
}
```

If the any session variable exist for search key the the index action returns data according to the search value otherwise returns all data. and also sending the search key through ViewBag.

```js
ViewBag.search_key = search_key;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="key" placeholder="Search data" name="search" value="@(ViewBag.search_key != null ? ViewBag.search_key : string.Empty)" />
```

Fetching the search key from ViewBag for showing the search key even after loading the page  with search results.

What I want is to remove search key and show all data after the page is fully refreshed or navigated to another page. is that possible to do? It should not remove the search key if only pagination index changes within the same page.

Comment: `After clicking on the search button I am saving the search string in a session variable and then loading the index again.` What's the reason to use a request to set a session variable and then another request to load a page, all of that can be done in a single "vanilla" POST.

Comment: You're right. I know the logic seems troublesome but this is the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

if you need that, you can use localStorage it is very useful and easy.

you can try it.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: No man then it won't be available in the server side.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Session.Remove("search_key").

Another way could be, to set the session variable for "search_key" to an invalid value e.g. string.Empty and evaluate this in your index.

Comment: I know I can remove it from session. The question is not how the question is when should I do this and from where so that the search string goes away after I change the page.

Comment: Ok, but your question was, is it possible to remove, not when . Think in this case the simplest way is to send your search_key with every request, if needed. Or what do you try to achieve by setting a session variable?

Comment: setting the session variable so that the index action itself can get the search_key from session and return the view according to the search criteria if there is any.

Comment: Mhh, so maybe you clear this session variable on the first load of the page, this will ensure, that you have no search criteria when loading from another page and as long as you are only doing kind of reloads for page indexes or something like that, the session war remains if set?

Comment: As I said the Index action is called every time after setting the session string in a session variable. So if I remove it while loading the page the search string will also be lost and I will not be able to show it in the search box.